# How to select the inverse of the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am successful in selecting the first `<li>` of the `<ul>`.

I want to select the remaining of the `<li>` except the current selected `<li>` . i.e., (inverse).

How can I select it?

Edited as per request

```
var newEle = $(str); //str contains a <li> i.e., <li>Some content</li>
$(newEle).hide();
```

Comment: Could you post the script you currently use? Probably it's just an insertion of an ! or .not() somewhere, but it'd be easier if we had your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ Solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the result of your selection in an Array you can use the jQuery methods `pop()` or `splice(begin,end)` to select the elements you want. Both are documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Types) (right before "Boolean default" headline).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

```
<ul id='myUL'>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$('ul#myUL > li').each(function(index) {
     if( index !=  '0'){
          alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
     }
});
```

[Check](http://jsfiddle.net/vBQch/)